# MoonMail installation issue - error during resource deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, moonmail

I am trying to do setup of moon mail following this https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail

I have successfully done these step

```
npm install
cd events/
npm install
cd ../api/
npm install
```

Initialize the Serverless project:

```
sls project init -c -n your-lower-case-project-name
```

I also added the file `s-variables-<stage>-<region> where stage is the stage of my serverless i.e prod and region is us-west-2`

When I run this command

```
sls resources deploy
```

I face these errors

[image]

[image]

I have already added the default variables into the `s-variables-<stage>-<region>` file but still the warning is being shown for these variables.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see the problem is that you are still missing a couple variables which are required to deploy DynamoDB tables and indexes, you need to set in your `s-variables-<stage>` all those ending in `RCU` and `WCU` (Read and Write Capacity Units).

You will notice that we have `defaultRCU` and `defaultWCU` but others like `campaignsRCU` and `campaingsWCU`, this is because we want to use different capacities for different tables and indexes according to our usage patterns but what I recommend is to replace everything ending in `WCU` or `RCU`by `defaultWCU` and `defaultRCU` respectively inside https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/blob/master/s-resources-cf.json so you only have to configure these 2 variables in your `s-variables-<stage>`. Hope it helps.